# R outer product of factors - custom mapping - way too slow

Tags: r, performance, categorical-data

Given two factors (each with the same set of levels), say

```
lev <- c("alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "echo", "delta", "foxtrot")
A <- factor(sample(lev, 6000, TRUE))
B <- factor(sample(lev, 6000, TRUE))
```

I want to take their outer product, with a custom product function, defined like so:

```
mapping <- matrix(c(
    "green", "blue",  "blue",  "red",    "red",    "red",
    "blue",  "green", "blue",  "red",    "red",    "red",
    "blue",  "blue",  "green", "red",    "red",    "red",
    "red",   "red",   "red",   "green",  "yellow", "red",
    "red",   "red",   "red",   "yellow", "green",  "red",
    "red",   "red",   "red",   "red",    "red",    "green"),
    nrow=6, ncol=6,
    dimnames=list(lev, lev))
mapper <- function (X, Y) mapping[matrix(c(levels(X)[X], levels(Y)[Y]),
                                         ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)]
A.B <- outer(A, B, FUN=mapper)
```

Expected output (for a considerably reduced test case) is supposed to be something like

```
> A
[1] alpha   foxtrot echo    charlie echo    foxtrot bravo   delta   charlie
Levels: alpha bravo charlie delta echo foxtrot
> B
[1] alpha   foxtrot delta   bravo   bravo   alpha   alpha   bravo   alpha  
Levels: alpha bravo delta foxtrot
> outer(A, B, mapper)
      [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]    [,6]    [,7]    [,8]    [,9]   
 [1,] "red"  "red"  "red"  "red"  "red"   "green" "green" "green" "green"
 [2,] "red"  "red"  "red"  "red"  "red"   "green" "green" "green" "green"
 [3,] "red"  "red"  "red"  "red"  "red"   "green" "green" "green" "green"
 [4,] "red"  "red"  "red"  "red"  "red"   "green" "green" "green" "green"
 [5,] "blue" "blue" "blue" "blue" "blue"  "red"   "green" "green" "blue" 
 [6,] "red"  "red"  "red"  "red"  "green" "green" "green" "green" "green"
 [7,] "red"  "red"  "red"  "red"  "green" "green" "green" "green" "green"
 [8,] "red"  "red"  "red"  "red"  "green" "green" "green" "green" "green"
 [9,] "red"  "red"  "red"  "red"  "green" "green" "green" "green" "green"
```

This works, but at the full scale it is unpleasantly slow:

```
> system.time(outer(A, B, mapper))
   user  system elapsed 
 11.381   5.015  17.653
```

Can anyone recommend a faster way?  In case it helps, the mapping matrix is guaranteed to be triangular (i.e. `mapping[a,b] == mapping[b,a]` ∀ a,b.)

Comment: Small question: did you mean `sample(lev, 6000, TRUE)`? Otherwise you just get `NA`s, I think...

Comment: Also can you give some desired output just to make sure we get the correct answer?

Comment: Just thinking about this a bit, my first reaction is to wonder whether you have to have a (triangular) matrix output. This feels more like a join (or merge) to me.

Comment: And you really want `A.B` to be a 6000*6000 matrix?

Comment: @joran It needn't necessarily be a matrix; `outer()` was just the first thing I found that did the job.  It's going to be visualized as a bitmap, with each of the output-factor values mapped to a color.

Comment: @MrFlick Yes, `6000*6000` is the correct size.

Comment: `mapping` isn't a two dimensional array (matrix) either. Take a look at it; it is one dimensional.

Comment: Aheh.  Trying to produce sample output on a reduced scale caused me to discover that the mapping doesn't do what I thought it would.  Please stay tuned.

Comment: All answerers please reread updated question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*EDIT*: It seems the question changed dramatically while I was answering, but leaving this here anyway.

---

I am assuming @joran's comment is correct and you meant (and fixing the order in `lev`)

```
lev <- c("alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "delta", "echo", "foxtrot")
A <- factor(sample(lev, 6000, TRUE), levels=lev)
B <- factor(sample(lev, 6000, TRUE), levels=lev)
```

Also, `mapping` is not a two dimensional array (matrix) nor a nested data structure (list of lists) like you seem to think

```
> mapping
    alpha.alpha     alpha.bravo   alpha.charlie     alpha.delta      alpha.echo 
        "green"          "blue"          "blue"           "red"           "red" 
  alpha.foxtrot     bravo.alpha     bravo.bravo   bravo.charlie     bravo.delta 
          "red"          "blue"         "green"          "blue"           "red" 
     bravo.echo   bravo.foxtrot   charlie.alpha   charlie.bravo charlie.charlie 
          "red"           "red"          "blue"          "blue"         "green" 
  charlie.delta    charlie.echo charlie.foxtrot     delta.alpha     delta.bravo 
          "red"           "red"           "red"           "red"           "red" 
  delta.charlie     delta.delta      delta.echo   delta.foxtrot      echo.alpha 
          "red"         "green"        "yellow"           "red"           "red" 
     echo.bravo    echo.charlie      echo.delta       echo.echo    echo.foxtrot 
          "red"           "red"        "yellow"           "red"           "red" 
  foxtrot.alpha   foxtrot.bravo foxtrot.charlie   foxtrot.delta    foxtrot.echo 
          "red"           "red"           "red"           "red"           "red" 
foxtrot.foxtrot 
        "green"
```

Now, if you want to store this as a list of lists:

```
mapping <- list(
    "alpha"   = list("alpha"="green", "bravo"="blue", "charlie"="blue",
                     "delta"="red", "echo"="red", "foxtrot"="red"),
    "bravo"   = list("alpha"="blue", "bravo"="green", "charlie"="blue",
                     "delta"="red", "echo"="red", "foxtrot"="red"),
    "charlie" = list("alpha"="blue", "bravo"="blue", "charlie"="green",
                     "delta"="red", "echo"="red", "foxtrot"="red"),
    "delta"   = list("alpha"="red", "bravo"="red", "charlie"="red",
                     "delta"="green", "echo"="yellow", "foxtrot"="red"),
    "echo"    = list("alpha"="red", "bravo"="red", "charlie"="red",
                     "delta"="yellow", "echo"="red", "foxtrot"="red"),
    "foxtrot" = list("alpha"="red", "bravo"="red", "charlie"="red",
                     "delta"="red", "echo"="red", "foxtrot"="green")
)
mapper = function(X, Y) mapping[[levels(X)[X]]][[levels(Y)[Y]]]
```

Note that I'm using `list` instead of `c` in creating `mapping` and that `mapper` uses the extractor (`[[`) not subsetting (`[`) notation.

Checking this works for a single value:

```
> mapper(A[1], B[1])
[1] "red"
```

And for only a few values:

```
> mapper(A[1:2], B[1:2])
Error in mapping[[levels(X)[X]]][[levels(Y)[Y]]] : 
  attempt to select more than one element
```

So we see `mapper` is not vectorized (as it must be). From the help page of `outer`:

> `FUN` is called with these two extended vectors as arguments. Therefore, it must be a vectorized function (or the name of one), expecting at least two arguments.

The easy, but not necessarily efficient, way to vectorize it:

```
> Vectorize(mapper)(A[1:2], B[1:2])
[1] "red"   "green"
```

This now works on a subset:

```
> outer(A[1:6], B[1:6], FUN=Vectorize(mapper))
     [,1]    [,2]     [,3]    [,4]    [,5]    [,6]    
[1,] "red"   "yellow" "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   
[2,] "red"   "green"  "red"   "red"   "red"   "yellow"
[3,] "red"   "green"  "red"   "red"   "red"   "yellow"
[4,] "blue"  "red"    "blue"  "red"   "blue"  "red"   
[5,] "green" "red"    "green" "red"   "green" "red"   
[6,] "red"   "red"    "red"   "green" "red"   "red"
```

Let's check the timings:

```
> system.time(outer(A[1:6], B[1:6], FUN=Vectorize(mapper)))
   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0 
> system.time(outer(A[1:60], B[1:60], FUN=Vectorize(mapper)))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.22    0.00    0.22 
> system.time(outer(A[1:600], B[1:600], FUN=Vectorize(mapper)))
   user  system elapsed 
  23.97    0.01   24.01
```

Looks about linear in the length of the outer product, or quadratic in the length of A or B. I didn't wait 40 minutes to see if the 6000x6000 would work.

Can we make this a lot more efficient? Double indexing into a recursive structure (and then having to use `Vectorize` on top of that) is not that efficient. Let's use a different data structure: a two dimensional array (matrix) and use matrix based indexing.

```
mapping <- matrix(c("green", "blue", "blue", "red", "red", "red", 
                    "blue", "green", "blue", "red", "red", "red", 
                    "blue", "blue", "green", "red", "red", "red",
                    "red", "red", "red", "green", "yellow", "red", 
                    "red", "red", "red", "yellow", "red", "red", 
                    "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "green"),
                  nrow = 6, ncol = 6,
                  dimnames = list(lev, lev))
mapper <- function(X, Y) mapping[cbind(as.character(X), as.character(Y))]
```

And testing this

```
> A[1:6]
[1] echo    delta   delta   charlie alpha   foxtrot
Levels: alpha bravo charlie echo delta foxtrot
> B[1:6]
[1] alpha   delta   alpha   foxtrot alpha   echo   
Levels: alpha bravo charlie echo delta foxtrot
> mapper(A[1], B[1])
[1] "red"
> mapper(A[1:2], B[1:2])
[1] "red"   "green"
> outer(A[1:6], B[1:6], FUN=mapper)
     [,1]    [,2]     [,3]    [,4]    [,5]    [,6]    
[1,] "red"   "yellow" "red"   "red"   "red"   "red"   
[2,] "red"   "green"  "red"   "red"   "red"   "yellow"
[3,] "red"   "green"  "red"   "red"   "red"   "yellow"
[4,] "blue"  "red"    "blue"  "red"   "blue"  "red"   
[5,] "green" "red"    "green" "red"   "green" "red"   
[6,] "red"   "red"    "red"   "green" "red"   "red"
```

Looks good. Check timings:

```
> system.time(outer(A[1:6], B[1:6], FUN=mapper))
   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0 
> system.time(outer(A[1:60], B[1:60], FUN=mapper))
   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0 
> system.time(outer(A[1:600], B[1:600], FUN=mapper))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.22    0.00    0.22 
> system.time(outer(A, B, FUN=mapper))
   user  system elapsed 
   7.80    1.48    9.30
```

A little over 9 seconds instead of ~40 minutes for about a 250 times speedup.

Comment: Thanks for explaining *why* the original version of the question turned out not to work.  I can't say I really grok R's data structure handling; usually I just have a big data frame and I know how to use `lm` and `ggplot` ;-)

Comment: Note this is slower than what @MrFlick is reporting due to your use of character index matrix (see my answer; numerics are way faster).

Comment: Numeric indexing will be faster than character indexing, but I thought this was clearer as to intent (and didn't feel the need to squeeze even more efficiency out of it). For an even more efficient solution, recognizing the assumptions about the mapping of labels to indexes that needs to be made, using the numeric version would be preferred.

Answer (score 2):

So, your `mapping` variable isn't quite right. If you look at

```
str(mapping)
#  Named chr [1:36] "green" "blue" "blue" "red" "red" "red" ...
#  - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:36] "alpha.alpha" "alpha.bravo" "alpha.charlie" ...
```

You'll see that it's a one dimensional character vector. There the names of the elements are are pasted together with a ".". I'm assuming this is not what you wanted. Perhaps you had used `list()` rather than `c()`? But if you can control the format, why not use a simple matrix

```
mapping <- structure(c("green", "blue", "blue", "red", "red", "red", "blue", 
"green", "blue", "red", "red", "red", "blue", "blue", "green", 
"red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "green", "yellow", 
"red", "red", "red", "red", "yellow", "red", "red", "red", "red", 
"red", "red", "red", "green"), .Dim = c(6L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "echo", "delta", "foxtrot"
    ), c("alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "echo", "delta", "foxtrot"
    )))
```

So there's a row and column for each value of `lev` and the color of the cell is the color of the combination.

Then if you do

```
#sample data
lev <- c("alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "echo", "delta", "foxtrot")
A <- factor(sample(lev, 6000, TRUE), levels=lev)
B <- factor(sample(lev, 6000, TRUE), levels=lev)

#run mapping
out <- outer(A, B, FUN=function(a,b) mapping[cbind(a,b)])
```

Now out will have values of A along the rows and values of B along the cols and the correct color for the interaction between the two as a cell value. This runs pretty quickly

```
system.time(outer(A, B, FUN=function(a,b) mapping[cbind(a,b)]))

#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.90    0.25    1.15
```

Comment: Hmm.  I came up with something similar (see edited question) after realizing that my code didn't do anything like what I thought it did.  Your version is somewhat faster, but still takes 5 seconds (elapsed) on this computer - maybe yours is just faster?

Comment: Perhaps. Either way it's no where near the 15+ minutes you first reported.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does what you want, in about 4 seconds (runs about 4x faster if you don't add names, but result doesn't look as good).  Note, very important: **this only works if the levels are the same for `A` and `B` and the levels are the same as the names of `mapping.mx`**.  This is because `cbind` coerces factors to numeric, so the mapping is positional.  If not the case, you can coerce `A` and `B` to character, and it will work, but be slower still.

```
names(A) <- A
names(B) <- B

mapping.mx <- do.call(rbind, mapping.lst)  # see below for mapping.lst
system.time(res <- outer(A, B, function(x, y) mapping.mx[cbind(x, y)]))

# user  system elapsed 
# 3.33    0.62    3.95 

str(res)

# chr [1:6000, 1:6000] "red" "green" "green" "blue" "green" "blue" ...
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  ..$ : chr [1:6000] "delta" "alpha" "alpha" "bravo" ...
#  ..$ : chr [1:6000] "alpha" "alpha" "echo" "delta" ...

res[1:5, 1:5]

#       alpha   alpha   echo     delta charlie
# delta "red"   "red"   "yellow" "red" "red"  
# alpha "green" "green" "red"    "red" "blue" 
# alpha "green" "green" "red"    "red" "blue" 
# bravo "blue"  "blue"  "red"    "red" "blue" 
# alpha "green" "green" "red"    "red" "blue"
```

And `mapping.lst` (basically, the same as yours, but changed the first `c` to a `list`):

```
mapping.lst <- list(
  "alpha"   = c("alpha"="green", "bravo"="blue", "charlie"="blue",
                "delta"="red", "echo"="red", "foxtrot"="red"),
  "bravo"   = c("alpha"="blue", "bravo"="green", "charlie"="blue",
                "delta"="red", "echo"="red", "foxtrot"="red"),
  "charlie" = c("alpha"="blue", "bravo"="blue", "charlie"="green",
                "delta"="red", "echo"="red", "foxtrot"="red"),
  "delta"   = c("alpha"="red", "bravo"="red", "charlie"="red",
                "delta"="green", "echo"="yellow", "foxtrot"="red"),
  "echo"    = c("alpha"="red", "bravo"="red", "charlie"="red",
                "delta"="yellow", "echo"="red", "foxtrot"="red"),
  "foxtrot" = c("alpha"="red", "bravo"="red", "charlie"="red",
                "delta"="red", "echo"="red", "foxtrot"="green")
)
```